# How to loop through keys in a dict to find the corresponding value?

Tags: python

When a user enters a name (e.g. "Jim") as an argument for an instance of my "Test" class, the `def find` function is called and for-loops through all the names in the dict matching "Jim".  If `def find` finds the key word "Jim" in the dict, then it should print out the corresponding value.  But when I run the code it just says "None". What do I need to change so that invoking `def find` results in the print statement 'worked'??

```
class Test(object): 
    def __init__(self, x=0): # error in (def find)?
        self.x = x

    c = None                 # error while looping in the for loop?
    users = {
        'John': 1,
        'Jim':  2,
        'Bob':  3
    }

    def find(self, x):       # The user is supposed to type in the name "x"

        for self.c in self.users:         # it goes through the dictionary 
            if x == self.users[self.c]:   # If x is equal to key it prints worked
                print('worked')
            else:
                pass


beta = Test()
print(beta.find('Jim'))
```

Comment: The `for` loop needs to be indented.

Comment: Also the `else` needs to be indented.

Comment: It is that's just the copy and paste

Comment: Your code does not seem right, and just by copy pasting your code and doing minor indentation fixes, I'm getting another error that does not match what you are explaining is happening. Please fix your indentation, ensure that this is in fact the latest code you are working with.

Comment: If that's the case, then format your question correctly to be up to Stack Overflow standards. Read the Help Centre to create good questions. As it stands, lack of editing work leads to sloppy questions.

Comment: Why on Earth are you doing `for self.c in self.users:`? `for c in self.users:` works just fine, you only assign to `self.<someattr>` when it's instance state, which this is not (it's just local state for the test). You're not even using instance related features here, so it's a little unclear why you even need a class.

Comment: I fixed the indentation

Comment: The `print()` function also needs to be indented

Comment: The `pass` code is also incorrectly spaced.

Comment: @nk001: You did not. You've still got illegal indentation all over the place. Even with another user's changes (which aren't necessarily correct), your `__init__` has no body (and no purpose; it sets state you never use).

Comment: `self.x` requires indentation

Comment: If you aren't going to put effort into your questions, then don't bother asking them on a site like SO.

Comment: @nk001 Be sure to accept and upvote one of the answers.

Comment: @nk001 Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code was returning `None` because you had not specified a value for the function to return. I second @techydesigner, you'll do well to accept and upvote useful comments and any helpful answers as well as accept (the check mark under the up/down arrows) an answer which answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nk001,
I think this is a little more like what you are trying for:

```
class Test(object): 
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x               # <-- indent the __init__ statements

    users = {                    # <-- users = {
        'John': 1,               #         KEY: VALUE,
        'Jim':  2,               #         KEY: VALUE,
        'Bob':  3                #         KEY: VALUE,
    }                            #     }

    def find(self, x):             # <-- The user passes the "x" argument

        for i in self.users:       # <-- Now it goes through the dictionary 
            if x == i:             # <-- If ARGV('x') == KEY
                return 'worked'    # <-- Then RETURN 'worked'
            else:
                pass


beta = Test()
print(beta.find("Jim"), beta.users["Jim"])
```

There's a couple different ways to get the 'worked' msg and the corresponding Value printed, this is just an example to demonstrate accessing the dict[KEY] to get the VALUE.

Also, I'm just assuming you meant an if/else block, and not a for/else? Indentation is critical w/Python. Also, your original script was returning None because there was no explicit `return` in your for loop - hence, when the function is called in the printing statement `print(beta.find('Jim'))` when the function finishes it returns nothing ("None"). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I write a worked code:

```
class Test(object):
    users = {
        'John': 1,
        'Jim': 2,
        'Bob': 3
    }

    def __init__(self, x=0): # So I don't get an error in (def find)
        self.x = x

    def find(self, x):  # The user is suppose to type in the name "x"
        for name in Test.users.keys():   # it goes through the dictionary
            if x == name: # If x is equal to key it prints worked
                print('worked', self.users[name])
            else:
                pass


beta = Test()
beta.find('Jim')
```

1. You don not need the `self.c`.
2. The `users` is a class variable, you need to visit it by `Test.users`.
3. Your names is stored as the keys of the dict. So you need to get them by `Test.users.keys()`
4. The statement `print(beta.find('Jim'))` will print the return value of the `find`. But you don't return a value manually, you will get a `None` in your output.

Comment: @nk001, note the difference between your explicit call to `print` with`print(beta.find('Jim'))` and @yundongxu's `beta.find('Jim')`